# SAS Index function?

Tags: indexing, sas

Can anyone explain why the below piece of code gives two different values?

```
87   data _null_;
88      length a b $14;
89      a = 'ABC.DEF (X=Y)';
90      b = 'X=Y';
91      x = index(a,b);
92      y = index('ABC.DEF (X=Y)','X=Y');
93      put x y;
94   run;

0 10
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It seems this is an exact copy of [the example on the SAS website](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212242.htm), so it would have been helpful if you would have looked for an answer there first.

This is their explanation:

## Example 2:

### Removing Trailing Spaces When You Use the INDEX Function with the TRIM Function

The following example shows the results when you use the INDEX function with and without the TRIM function. If you use INDEX without the TRIM function, leading and trailing spaces are considered part of the excerpt argument. If you use INDEX with the TRIM function, TRIM removes trailing spaces from the excerpt argument as you can see in this example. Note that the TRIM function is used inside the INDEX function.
options nodate nostimer ls=78 ps=60;

```
data _null_;
   length a b $14;
   a='ABC.DEF (X=Y)';
   b='X=Y';
   q=index(a,b);
   w=index(a,trim(b));
   put q= w=;
run;
```

SAS writes the following output to the log:

```
q=0 w=10
```

---

Added based on mjsqu's comment:

```
 data _null_;
   length a b $14 c $3;
   a='ABC.DEF (X=Y)';
   b='X=Y';
   c='X=Y';
   x=index(a,b);
   y=index(a,c);
   z=index(a,trim(b));
   d = "|" || a ||"|";
   e = "|" || b ||"|";
   f = "|" || c ||"|";
   put d=;
   put e=;
   put f=;
   put x= y= z=;
  run;

d=|ABC.DEF (X=Y) |
e=|X=Y           |
f=|X=Y|
x=0 y=10 z=10
```

You can see that b has a trailing space which is part of the string that the Index function will be looking for. Since in `string a` **X=Y** is followed by **)** and not a space, this means it will not be found => q = 0. You can also see here that if you change the length of b to the actual lenght of the string you want to look for (3 in this case), it would give you the same outcome.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't used the trim function. I would expect the x and y to have the same value as the values a and b are identical to the arguments of y. However this is not the case, any ideas?

Comment: Check the actual value of the `b` variable by running `put "|" b +(-1) "|";`, this should show that the variable has leading or trailing spaces. `'X=Y           '` or `'            X=Y'`, which isn't found in the value of `a`.

Comment: @mjsqu I added your suggestion to my answer for clarification. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Yohsoog no problem, it looks like you made a better example anyway, good answer :)